# Need to add text to rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating Dynamic Rectangle and adding into `StackPanel`. I need to add text to each rectangle. How can I do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A Rectangle doesn't have any child content, so you will need to put both controls inside of another panel, such as a grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Stroke="Red" Fill="Blue"/>
    <TextBlock>some text</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

You can also use a Border control, which will take a single child and draw a rectangle around it:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue">
    <TextBlock>some text</TextBlock>
</Border>
```

You say "dynamic rectangle", so it sounds like you are doing this in code.  The equivalent C# would look something like this:

```
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Children.Add(new Rectangle() { Stroke = Brushes.Red, Fill = Brushes.Blue });
grid.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "some text" });
panel.Children.Add(grid);
// or
panel.Children.Add(new Border()
{
    BorderBrush = Brushes.Red,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
    Background = Brushes.Blue,
    Child = new TextBlock() { Text = "some text" },
});
```

But if you want a dynamic list of rectangles, you should probably use an ItemsControl:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If you set the DataContext to a list of objects, this XAML will create a Border with a TextBlock for each one with the text set to the Text property on the object.

Comment: Could you please provide some code snippets for Binding the Datacontext of Itemcontrol.

Answer (score 6):

First of all you can do this, but not by adding the control. And there is a very good reason to do this, for high speed hardware rendering. You can create a special brush from a UI element that caches itself in hardware and fill the rectangle with this hardware, and it is extremely fast. I will just show the code behind because it is the example I have offhand

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
r.StrokeThickness = 5;
r.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
r.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
r.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
r.Margin = new Thickness(0);
r.Width = 200;
r.Height = 200;
r.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(100, 100);
TextBlock TB = new TextBlock();
TB.Text = "Some Text to fill";
// The next two magical lines create a special brush that contains a bitmap
// rendering of the UI element that can then be used like any other brush
// and it's in hardware and is almost the text book example for utilizing 
// all hardware rending performances in WPF unleashed 4.5
BitmapCacheBrush bcb = new BitmapCacheBrush(TB);
r.Fill = bcb;
MyCanvas.Children.Add(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a textual control to your StackPanel, such as [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) or [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx).

Comment: I need to add text inside Rectangle.How can i add Label into rectangle.